# Extracting software commonalities in a Agile Process

Tags: design-patterns

Recently i had the chance of working on a large software project which followed the Agile Process. When we began working on the project, a lot of the software requirements were not clear. However, the software lead made a mistake of developing a Framework which basically extracted commonalities and placed these in a super class. As the project progressed, a lot of requirements came clear and a lot of  existing requirements changed, which off course caused constant change in our "Framework" .

My question is, what should we do in such a case .

1. Extract commonalities, only once all the requirements are clear.
2. Do try any code optimization until the project is finished.
3. Go with the flow, and adapt the code as the requirements change.

Is there any anti-pattern that describes this scenario ? Alot of developers have a fascination with moving common functions to a super class ? What is the general feedback for this ?

Kind Regards

Comment: Sounds like a layer supertype. http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/layerSupertype.html In itself not an anti-pattern although any pattern can be misused.

Answer (score 3):

Extreme Programming (a flavour of agile development, though less fashionable now than in the past) has the principle of YAGNI - "You Ain't Gonna Need It". This advises against creating such frameworks up-front, or anything that doesn't directly support the current story. See http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt for more.

Of course, it's possible to take this too far. If a project is likely to need, say, logging/tracing, then it would be a lot of work to wait until you had a serviceability story in which the logs are used, and only then create a logging framework and go back and instrument all the classes with trace points, instead of doing it as a matter of course as you write the code.

So you need to be pragmatic and create just the *right* amount of "stuff that you foresee a need for". How much is the right amount I think is something you can only judge by experience.

In terms of your three options, I guess this is closest to number three. Refactoring code as you learn more about the problem and about the structure of your software is not a bad thing. Provided, that is, that your small-scale design (encapsulation, separation of concerns, etc) is good so that every change doesn't involve dozens of complex edits, and that you have good tests, which cover enough of the function but aren't tied too tightly to implementation. Then you can refactor with confidence as your design changes.

Comment: This sounds like what I believe agile to be. Start with something simple that works and add to it incrementally.

Answer (score 1):

That's a hard one. I've been there a few times. It's hard because usually we (as developers or architects) should strive for gathering the requirements up front...my teammates and me usually phrase that without requirements we shouldn't write a single line of code, or make any design decisions. Which is absolutely true, but, in real life it gets a bit complicated, sometimes customers don't even know what they want...however, the Executive Board wants to keep the customer happy and make them believe we are the best fit for their project (and in fact we are) by getting the ball rolling.

At that point we start architecting a "very flexible", maintainable, scalable system and then a couple of months later requirements change and we have to re-design the system's foundations. You'd wish there were a magic design pattern/guideline to follow and prevent this...well, unfortunately, there isn't.

You can always minimize the impact of such requirement creeps but no matter how flexible you've built your system you will always have to build it with a set of basic requirements in mind, if the requirements change, then the system might need to be changed as well.